# C# DateTime parsing international cultures

Tags: c#, parsing, date, internationalization, cultureinfo

I'm trying to parse a variety of date formats, the day number, time and year components are consistent but the day of the week and month are device dependent. These are some example results, coming from iPads

```
Isn Mac 11 16:25:58 2013

Ahd Mac 10 18:34:41 2013

Sab Mac 09 18:44:34 2013

Jum Mac 08 16:57:33 2013


Fri Mar 8 16:49:46 2013

Thu Mar 7 12:34:47 2013

Sat Jan 19 12:21:58 2013
```

The English ones parse fine but the Malaysian (Malay) ones never do

I was using this to debug it:

```
        var allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

        foreach (var culture in allCultures)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact("Isn Mac 11 16:25:58 2013", "ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyyy", culture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result))
                return;
        }
```

Ideally it would handle all possible languages in this format and I wouldn't have to write language specific code

I've tried manually parsing the Malaysian dates with the following culture codes:
ms
ms-BN
ms-MY

Any ideas?

Thanks for your time

Comment: Just read it back, I guess the day number isn't really consistent if it can be either 8 or 08, but that's easy to work around

Comment: for `08` or `8` you can using single `d` that will work for both.

Comment: So what have you tried?  You've tried your code and it fails to parse with `d` but works with `dd`?  And with `dd` if you pass in the date of `8` or `08` it fails?  More context of what you've tried and what the problem is please.

Comment: I've updated it a bit as the day number part is not a problem (thanks Habib that works either way). Its the first part, e.g "Isn Mac" vs "Fri Mar"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a bug in the `CultureInfo` data for Malasian cultures - the `AbbreviatedDayNames` array looks like this:

```
Ahad 
Isnin 
Sel 
Rabu 
Khamis 
Jumaat 
Sabtu
```

You will not that `Isn` doesn't exists as such - it is `Isnin`.

For comparison, look at `DayNames`:

```
Ahad 
Isnin 
Selasa 
Rabu 
Khamis 
Jumaat 
Sabtu
```

I had picked these out from:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ms-MY").DateTimeFormat
```

---

As a solution, see if you can use full day names - using `Isnin` instead of `Isn` in your example, returns the correct `DateTime` object.

Answer (score 1):

I have  tested your datetime with the malaysian culture. Obviously your string has the incorrect day name:

```
var dt = new DateTime(2013,03,11,16,25,58);
var currCult = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ms-MY");
var str = dt.ToString("ddd MMM d HH:mm:ss yyy", currCult);
// ---> "Isnin Mac 11 16:25:58 2013"
```

Imho `Isn` != `Isnin`,